# Is Qt raster- or vector-based? What about wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I heard that some GUI libraries are vector-based. And then I thought, "aren't they all?" Will a GUI application made using Qt be scalable? Same question for wxWidgets(?) If any of the two latter are raster-based, why is that the case, i.e., what would be the advantage of such a technology over scalable graphical interface libraries?

Comment: For wxWidgets, your question is best asked on the wxWidgets forum.

Comment: Not all graphic systems are vector based; most are raster based.  This makes drawing onto the physical medium easier, for example, LCD, PLASMA or Raster displays.  Although I have seen graphics that are vector based.  The vector based could hold more objects, but they had to be described by vectors (Imagine taking a photograph and converting to vectors).

Comment: Many graphics hardware support works with tiles, or sprites, or small matrices.  Using Linear Algebra, you can scale these using matrix multiplication.  The graphics support also includes binary operations, such as XOR, OR and AND.  For example taking a sprite and ANDing it with present background.

Comment: If you are asking about the advantage of Vector based graphics vs. Raster, it all depends on the application.  Drawings based on wire-frames are more efficiently drawn with vector based graphics than with raster.  Applications that use tiles are more efficiently drawn using raster technology.  Think about a 2d Mario Game.